# Is there a way to refer to an existing Maven Archetype from an Archetype I create

Tags: maven

I'm trying to make a new Maven Archetype for my organization. Basically, we want to use an existing Maven Archetype, but with a few extra changes.

I know that I could I could simply `generate` a project from the existing Archetype, modify it to contain our changes, and then use `create-from-project` to create my project. But I'm afraid that if I do it that way, it will be hard to update my custom Archetype with changes from the original Archetype, if the original ever changes.

Is there a way to build an Archetype in a referential way, i.e. "everything from this other Archetype, plus X"?

Comment: What do you mean by: "*But I'm afraid that if I do it that way, it will be hard to update my custom Archetype with changes from the original Archetype, if the original ever changes.*"

Comment: So, the Archetype I'm looking at is the NiFi Processor Archetype. It's for NiFi version 1.9.2. I want to make a new Archetype off of that Archetype, and use that as the basis for projects. But what happens when the NiFi Archetype changes, say to version 2? How do I update my Archetype to be based off of version 2? Do I have to do the whole process all over again?